# ArrayCollection not returning absolute length when filterfunction is apllied on it

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, blazeds

My Dataprovider for a grid is an arrayCollection which is dynamically loaded with Objects . for example : a person object with persionID,PersonName ..etc . I applied a filter function
on my dataprovider based on personID . below is my function

```
public function FilterFunc(item:Object):Boolean
            {
                var same:Boolean=String(item.personID ) == filterpersonID ;
                return same;
            }
```

this function works fine whenever i change my filterpersonID to person1,person2 ..showing the respective changes . But, when i applied a function to limit the no of items on the grid like

```
private function DPSizeHandler(dp:ArrayCollection):void
            {
                if (dp.length > 100)
                    dp.removeItemAt(0);
            }
```

this function is called whenever a new object is being added to the arraycollection . The problem now is dp.length in the above function is returning only the no of objects of the particular personID on which the filterFunction was applied instead of the absolute value . Its not limiting the size of the other objects which are runnning into thousand's causing memory issues . once i change the filterFunction to different personID , it slowly starts limiting the  respective personID objects. So the sizeHandler() limits only the personID objects for which filterfunction was applied instead of the whole objects , this is the problem .

P.S : i am loading these objects into arraycollection from a JMS queue using blazeDS Consumer component which is fairly fast . i would really appreciate any help on this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing filter condition will not refresh array collection immediately, for that you will have to first call dp.refresh(), that will apply filter to your internal collection and then you will get correct length.

Comment: yea after changing the 'filterpersonID' i am calling dp.refresh()

Comment: I think your question is little confusing, you want length of all items without filter being applied on? then you will have to check dp.source.length, or remove the filter check length and apply filter back on.

Answer (score 1):

The raw, unfiltered list length can be accessed through

```
dp.list.length;
```

if that's what you mean by 'absolute';

Comment: Its actually dp.source.length, but the idea is correct. The length of the ArrayCollection will hold the number of items after the filter, and for good reason. :)

Comment: Could you elaborate more, why `source` is better for accessing raw data length than `list`?

Comment: to be honest, I wasn't even aware list was a property of ArrayCollection. I have always seen it done using the source property, so I assumed it was a typo. It seems like list could actually be a better one to use since it is a property of ListCollectionView, while source is not. Either way, my apologizes for the incorrect correction. :)